# Can home_url() be dynamically passed to a theme built with React?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, url, wordpress-theming

Testing out and building a WordPress theme in React I've typically seen the URL hard coded in a `componentDidMount` like:

```
class Home extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        const API_URL = 'https://foobar/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/';
        this.serverRequest = $.get(API_URL, function (result) {
            this.setState({
                result:result,
                loaded:true
            });
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
export default Home;
```

but I was curious to know if there was a way in the functions.php -> Home.js I can pass [`home_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url), in the example `https://foobar`, without having to manually modify Home.js?

Per querying the site with the paramters [[wordpress][reactjs]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress+reactjs) I've been unable to find if this is asked.  Can this be done or a way to pass the `wp-json/wp/v2` to React dynamically?

---

**Edit:**

There appears to be some confusion in what I'm trying to do.  If you were to use Axios with React instead of fetch, example from [Using Axios with React](https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/), you'd have to use a `GET` to pull the WP_JSON from WordPress.  The example link uses:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
        .then(res => {
            const persons = res.data;
            this.setState({ persons });
        })
}
```

the URL, `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`, is static and every time I were to load this theme to a new site, the URL will need to be changed.  How can I change the present URL to match the theme's hosted URL dynamically so that if the domain were to change from:

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
```

to

```
https://jsonwinners.typicode.com/users
```

I wouldn't have to do it manually.

Comment: your asking how to make the url dynamic?

Comment: While your question actually doesn't include quite enough detail to help specifically, in general - yes.  I'd recommend checking the [using AJAX in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) post - NOT because you're asking that question, but rather because it reveals how to "share" information from PHP to javascript files using [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

Comment: Sorry if there is a confusion.  I'm trying to figure out how to call the WP_API from WordPress in React without manually modifying `componentDidMount`.  If the theme were to be loaded by a different URL, such as `https://friday/` the fetch would still work.

Comment: Even given your clarification, my point / solution is still a viable option.  The question is: what is the context of your react code? Is it running within a WP theme? If so, then the localize_script option is totally legit. (Note - I use this exact strategy in my WordPress Angular apps)

Comment: Still researching, reading and testing to build it.  My understanding is I can do `create-react-app` but I'll have to have the index.php, functions.php as bare min.  There isn't much written on how to develop and when I browse repos on Github I'm finding minimal options.

Comment: I could probably build the entire site without issue but it would bug me to have to modify the URL manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from what you're trying to achieve, i would rather use `document.location.origin`

however, to answer your question, you *CAN* get php to send a variable to javascript....

---

### Method 1 (dirty) - custom script tag in the head

```
add_action('wp_head', function(){
     echo '<script>var MY_OBJ.users_url = "'.home_url('/users').'";</script>';
});
```

and then in your js file...

```
 componentDidMount() {
      axios.get(MY_OBJ.users_url)
         .then(res => {
             const persons = res.data;
              this.setState({ persons });
         })
 }
```

---

### Method 2 - localized script

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'home-js', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/js/Home.js'), array(), '1.0', true );

$my_php_array = array(
    'home_url' => home_url('')
    'users_url' => home_url('/users')
);

wp_localize_script( 'home-js', 'MY_OBJ', $my_php_array );
```

and then in your js file...

```
 componentDidMount() {
      axios.get(MY_OBJ.users_url)
         .then(res => {
             const persons = res.data;
              this.setState({ persons });
         })
 }
```